# Mudar separador dos campos de um MacAddress

Tags: javascript, replace

Gostaria de implementar um evento que corrigisse dados que viessem fora do padrão, substituindo o separador por `:` e colocando as letras em minúsculo. Por exemplo, o usuário digita `00-25-66-F0-21-11`, seria corrigido para `00:25:66:f0:21:11`.

Meu código atual:

```
<html>

<form name="muda">MAC: <input type="text" name="mac" id="macad" onmouseover="capturamac()" /></form>

<script>
function capturamac(){
    var macadd = toString(muda.mac.value);
    var corrige = macadd.split('-').join(':').toLowerCase();
    document.getElementById('macad').value = toString.corrige;
}
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: e qual o problema com o seu código? não está certo??

Comment: Está dando _[object Undefined]_

Comment: O `toString` está no lugar errado. Seria: `muda.mac.value.toString()`. Se bem que nem precisa converter pra string, já que o valor já parece ser uma string. Mas a resposta do Sorack já disse tudo :D

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa é usar [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) para quebrar a string em um array, e em seguida usar [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) para gerar uma string novamente.

O parâmetro do `split` é o separador (no caso, `-`). Com isso, será gerado um array com as partes do endereço (`00`, `25`, etc). E o parâmetro do `join` é o novo separador (no caso, `:`), assim as partes do array serão unidas em uma única string, com as partes separadas por `:`. Por fim, usei `toLowerCase()` para transformar as letras em minúsculas:

```js
let endereco = '00-25-66-F0-21-11';

let correto = endereco.split('-').join(':').toLowerCase();

console.log(correto); // 00:25:66:f0:21:11
```

---

Como você só está trocando um único caractere por outro, acho esta solução mais fácil. Mas a [solução do @Sorack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/347818/112052) com regex também é válida, e eu usaria ela para casos mais complexos (quando o separador não é apenas um único caractere, ou pode ser "qualquer caractere minúsculo ou dígitos", ou qualquer outro critério que seja mais fácil fazer com regex).

---

Quanto ao erro do *Object undefined*, ele ocorre por causa da forma que você está tentando capturar o valor do `input` e depois setá-lo de volta.

Por exemplo, chamar `toString` é desnecessário, pois o valor [já é uma string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties). E `onmouseover` chama a função de conversão quando o mouse é colocado sobre o campo.
O certo seria converter o valor somente depois que o foco é retirado do campo, e para isso usa-se [`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/blur).

O código corrigido fica assim:

```js
function capturamac(){
    var macadd = muda.mac.value;
    var corrige = macadd.split('-').join(':').toLowerCase();
    muda.mac.value = corrige;
}
```

```html
<html>

<form name="muda">MAC: <input type="text" name="mac" id="macad" onblur="capturamac()" /></form>

</html>
```

Comment: Não estou conseguindo "imprimir" de volta o valor corrigido. Está dando _[object Undefined]_. É um campo input.

Comment: @AndersonFidelis Então há algum problema em outro lugar (e não na conversão em si). Eu sugiro que você [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/347816/edit) sua pergunta colocando exatamente o código que gera o erro (e em qual linha o erro ocorre).

Comment: Esse é o problema! não apresenta erro! Já converti para String, mas não consigo achar um jeito de corrigir

Comment: Se está dando *Object Undefined* é porque está referenciando algo que não existe. Ou é `muda`, ou `muda.mac`, ou `document.getElementById('mac')`, ou algum outro. Algum deles não existe. Verifique no console (F12 no Chrome e Firefox) se esses elementos existem na sua página

Comment: Pois é @hkotsubo, minha implementação é em _iframe_. Quando peço para verificar o código fonte ele não mostra o id.

Comment: Talvez seja isso então, para pegar elementos dentro de um iframe é um pouco mais chato: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1088544

Comment: Trouxe meu código para outro arquivo html para ver se era erro mesmo do _iframe_. Constatei que não.

Comment: @AndersonFidelis Atualizei a resposta, veja se agora resolve

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro utilize [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) na sua `string`:

> [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)
>
> O método toLowerCase() retorna a string chamada convertida para minúsculo.

Depois utilize [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
>
> ```
>  str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function)
> ```
>
> O método replace() retorna uma nova string com algum ou todas as combinações do padrão substituído por um substituto. O padrão pode ser uma string ou uma RegExp, e o substituto pode ser uma string ou uma função a ser chamada por cada combinação.

Note que o [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) pode receber uma `string` como segundo parâmetro, porém caso seja fornecido este tipo de dado, apenas a primeira ocorrência será substituída. Portanto recomendo a utilização de uma expressão regular:

```
/-/g
```

Onde será correspondido o caractere literal `-` e utilizado o modificador  `g` (global).

Aplicando isso em uma função de conversão:

```js
const converter = entrada => entrada.toLowerCase().replace(/-/g, ':');

console.log(converter('00-25-66-F0-21-11'));
```

A expressão acima procura o caractere literal `-` e utiliza o modificador  `g` (global).

Comment: Obrigado Sorack, só não entendi o _console.log_

Comment: @AndersonFidelis apenas para mostrar a informação mesmo, você pode substituir pela atribuição no campo

Comment: Perfeito, neste caso eu pus `console.log(converter(muda.mac.value))` e deu _[object Undefined]_

Comment: @AndersonFidelis Qual o `id` do campo?

Comment: @AndersonFidelis O problema deve estar no `muda` ou no `muda.mac`. Tente fazer `console.log(muda)` e `console.log(muda.mac)` para ver o que tem nessas variáveis

Comment: "muda" é o meu formulário! "mac" é o nome do campo input!